# rails, can't display postgres array count results in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Rails 4.2.1 Ruby 2.0.0

I want to display the results of a postgres array count query as a simple table in a rails view.  The table should have 2 columns; deployed and count.

I am able to successfully query postgres using the following SQL

```
select unnest(deployed), count(deployed) from current_customer_profiles group by current_customer_profiles.deployed;
```

The results of the postgres query are

```
deployed | count

on prem  | 4

saas     | 2
```

I have tried using `select_rows` and `find_by_sql` in rails:

```
@deployment = CurrentCustomerProfile.connection.select_rows('select unnest(deployed) as deployed, count(deployed) as count from current_customer_profiles group by current_customer_profiles.deployed')

@deployment = CurrentCustomerProfile.find_by_sql(%q{select unnest(deployed) as deployed, count(deployed) as count from current_customer_profiles group by current_customer_profiles.deployed})
```

I have tried many different ways to get the data to display as a simple table in a rails view.

The problems that I have faced are:

1. The string (deploy column) is shown as [] in the view instead of the value (interestingly the count displays fine, so the result looks like; [] 4 and [] 2)
2. The results are returned as a string of the deployed column and count, i.e. "on prem 4" instead of two columns, on prem, 4

Below are two view examples I have tried (in respective order of the two items above):

```
<% @deployment.each do |e| %>
    <%= e.deployed %> <%= e.count %>
<% end %>


<% @deployment.each do |b| %>
    <% b.each do |bb| %>
     <%= bb %>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I display the results of a count of the items in a postgres array in a table in a rails view?  This is my first post on stack overflow so please let me know if I should provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use this approach to the hash results

```
<% @deployment.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= key %> <%= value %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Count is an attribute, try this like

```
 <% @deployment.each do |e| %>
   <%= e['deployed'] %> <%= e['count'] %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This still didn't work for me.  I have added an answer with what I was able to get to work

Answer (score 0):

As query returns results in hashes so you would have to do it like this

```
 <% @deployment.each do |e| %>
   <%= e['deployed'] %> <%= e['count'] %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This still didn't work for me.  I have added an answer with what I was able to get to work